# Shinobi : position of the spokes in pie

Tags: ios, canvas, pie-chart, shinobi, cliptobounds

I would like to position spokes in pie to be put "outside" of the pie. 
My problem is that on top and bottom, spokes need to go out of the "box" of the chart view.
This lead to spokes be inverted and placed in wrong direction.

[image]

I placed

```
self.clipsToBounds = false
self.canvas.clipsToBounds = false
```

My question is how to persuade chart to dray outside the bounds, or how to put padding around the chart.

Marko

Answer (score 0):

Pasting my answer from https://forum.shinobicontrols.com/t/position-of-the-spokes-in-pie/1693 in case it helps anyone here:

You can adjust the radius of the donut chart by setting `donutSeries.outerRadius`, and the length of the spokes by setting `donutSeries.style().spokeStyle.length`. Decreasing the outer radius and possibly also increasing the spoke length should give you the effect you're looking for.